# recovery value in a while

Tags: php, while-loop

I create this code to display a list of countries, I would retrieve the selected country but it does not work

```
<?php
include 'includes/combo.php';
?>

<?php
echo "<label for='pays'>Pays*</label>
        <select id='pays' name='pays '>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($combo)) {
    echo "<option>$row[0]</option>";
}
echo "</select> ";
echo "<option>$row[0]</option>";
?>
```

and recover with a

```
if(isset($_POST['pays']))      
    $pays=$_POST['pays'];
else
  $pays="";

echo $pays;
```

but the pays value is not recouped

Comment: `name='pays '` remove it space `name='pays'`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo"<option value=" . $row[0] . ">$row[0]</option>";
```

To retrieve the value of your option

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
include 'includes/combo.php';
?>

<?php
echo '<label for="pays">Pays*</label>
       <select id="pays" name="pays">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($combo)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[0] . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

You have one space after name in select
And your option hasn't value attribut